# How do you find the intersection of two subspaces U ∩ T?

Tags: linear-algebra

How would I find U ∩ T where

U = [(a, a, b, b) | a, b ∈ C]

T = [(a, b, 2a, 2b) | a, b ∈ C]

Comment: What's C here? Be more precise.

Comment: One technique would be to find a basis for each, use those as column vectors to form a matrix $A$, and solve for $Ax=0$. Each nontrivial solution $x$ represents a linear combination of the basis vectors in $U$ that is equal to a linear combination of the basis vectors in $T$.

Comment: Another technique (different way of doing the same thing) would be to set up a system of equations: $x_1=x_2$, $x_3=x_4$, $x_3=2x_1$, and $x_4=2x_2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(x,y,z,w)\in\mathbb{C^4}$

1. $(x,y,z,w)\in U \iff x=y \text{ and } z=w$
2. $(x,y,z,w)\in T \iff z=2x \text{ and } w=2y$

Therefore if $(x,y,z,w)\in U \cap T$ then it must satisfy 1. and 2. , i.e :

3. $y=x$ , $z=2x$ , $w=z=2x$ $\text{ and }$ $2x=2x$

Therefore it is all the points of the form $(x,x,2x,2x)$.

Comment: That's right! thank you @Joe